# How to add the same chart multiple times in one dashboard?

Tags: apache-superset

I'm struggling with reusing one chart multiple times in one dashboard in apache-superset.
Is it possible to somehow reuse one chart several times in one dashboard with different values of filters applied? This would be very useful for viewing same metrics in different segments / for different products / customer types / geographical areas etc.

I couldn't find a way how to do it. Although it is quite straightforward to set different filter value for, say, different tab of the dashboard, it is not possible to add the same chart once it has been added to the dashboard, so only way I came up with is to copy each single chart in the dashboard n times where n is the sum of different filters I need.
I'm trying to create a dashboard having 20+ identical charts for 10 products in 5 countries, similar situation in different departments here..
Letting the users select each filter value from the dashboard filter is unusable as no one will want to do it and and hence will not do it.

Any advice how to achieve this or something similar would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for any advice in advance.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I'd like to do the same.